# Tabulator: loading huge dataset takes a lot of time

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using a tabulator to populate the data on my page. there are some concerns that I have 38 Tables getting populated, and in those tables, I have approximately 2000 rows of data in each.

The issue is, It is taking a lot of time to load the data: 30 min approx, yes 30 MINS!. and that is not acceptable by any means. I tried using the Pagination but unfortunately, we have a hard printing requirement, which is not getting fulfilled with the pagination ( as all the data is not available when we press ctrl + P.

I am using HTML Formatter, textarea, and fit columns.

Here is one of the tables that I am using:

```
    const someTable= new Tabulator('#someContainer', {
        layout: 'fitColumns',
        resizableRows: true,
        columns: [
            { title: 'f1', field: 'col1', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f2', field: 'col2', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f3', field: 'col3', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f4', field: 'col4', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f5', field: 'col5', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f6', field: 'col6', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' }
        ]
    });

    let someData = document.getElementById('someData').value;
    someData= JSON.parse(someData);
    someTable.addData(someData, true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        someTable.redraw(true);
    }, 100);
}
```

Can someone help me in understanding why is this happening? (I checked by removing the timeout too. does not help much).

Also, I tried using the progressive load but that also does not reduce the time.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are doing a lot of excess work for the Tabulator.

1. Creating the Tabulator.
2. Filling it with data.
3. Redrawing it.

These are all intensive tasks for the Tabulator.
You should create the table with the data.  This prevents the need from redrawing the table and will increase the load speed.  Here is your example modified.

```
    let someData = document.getElementById('someData').value;
    someData = JSON.parse(someData);
    const someTable = new Tabulator('#someContainer', {
        layout: 'fitColumns',
        resizableRows: true,
        data: someData,
        columns: [
            { title: 'f1', field: 'col1', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f2', field: 'col2', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f3', field: 'col3', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f4', field: 'col4', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f5', field: 'col5', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' },
            { title: 'f6', field: 'col6', sorter: 'string', headerSort: false, formatter: 'textarea' }
        ]
    });
```

With so many tables being loaded, you should look at optimization outside of Tabulator.  I don't think any user would look at all 38 tables at once.  You should put the most frequented tables at the top and create/load these when the page opens.  Then as the user scrolls, you should create/load the additional tables.
This is the same situation as lazy loading images, except with a Tabulator.

Comment: the problem as I mentioned in progressive loading is that, I will loose the printing capability at once. and hence this won't help. i would have selected pagination and virtual DOM but this will not help.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are needing to print all records from each of the 38 tables at once. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes Correct, entire content in all tables all at once.

Comment: If you re-arrange your code like the above, it will improve.  Do that and let me know if there has been some improvement.  So that I can think about a solution for loading all of the data, what exactly are the tables used for?  Are they interactive or just for viewing purposes?  Does the user just open the page and immediately print all the records?

Comment: Loading all tables at once will certainly cause the system to freeze up. that is an awful lot of processing you are trying to do all at once. you probably only want to initialise the data as it comes into view of the user